# format android dateTime picker

Tags: android, datepicker

does anyone know of a way to format the date that is returned from a dateTime picker?

the following is returned 
1/1/2012
i require
01/01/2012
any help would be appreciated

i currently have the following to set the date

```
date2.setText(new StringBuilder()
    .append(mDay).append(mMonth + 1)
    .append(mYear));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
String mDate="";
String mMon="";

if(mDay<10)
   mDate="0"+mDay;
if((mMonth+1)<10)
   mMon="0"+(mMonth + 1);

date2.setText(new StringBuilder()
    .append(mDate).append(mMon)
    .append(mYear));
```

or you can also use **[SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)**

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a [SimpleDateFormatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). And, since the `DatePicker` returns integer values for day, month, year, you should use a [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) to create a Date:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month, day);
    Date newDate = cal.getTime();

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String dateString = formatter.format(newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library that would make converting between date/time formats rather easy https://github.com/novoda/NovodaTime

Answer (score -1):

Use this function it will return that string which you have mentioned.

```
String create_date_string (Date time)
{
    String date = "";
    DateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH mm ss ");
    date = outputFormatter.format(time);
    String date_tokens[] = date.split(" ");

    return date_tokens[0];
}
```

hope it will help you.

use this in your OnDateSetListener

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.set(year, monthOfYear - 1, dayOfMonth);
    String str = create_date_string(calender.getTime());
    date2.setText(str);
}
```